# Getting a list of tests in CMake

Tags: cmake

My CMake project is structured with a submodule that is controlled by a third party. They have a test that is broken, and I'd like to disable it.

I thought this would be something like

```
add_subdirectory(thirdparty)
set_tests_properties(their_broken_test PROPERTIES DISABLED true)
```

But not so simple, CMake tells me this test doesn't exist.

So I tried to step back and get a list of all of the tests that CMake *does* think exists. But this is even more baffling:

```
project(cmaketest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0 FATAL_ERROR)

enable_testing()
add_test(ls /bin/ls)
get_property(LIST_OF_TESTS DIRECTORY . PROPERTY TESTS)
message(STATUS "Here are the tests: ${LIST_OF_TESTS}")
```

On CMake 3.10.2, this shows *no* tests. But on CMake 3.12.1, it shows the `ls` test.

Is this a bug? Or is there a way to do it with the older CMake? (3.10.2 is what is in the Ubuntu Bionic repos.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TESTS` property was added in CMake 3.12 ([release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/release/3.12.html#properties)):

> A TESTS directory property was added to hold the list of tests defined by the add_test() command.

You can do something like this to collect a list of test names as they're added.

```
if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS "3.12.0") 
  function(add_test)
    _add_test(${ARGN})

    # There are two signatures to the add_test function to handle
    if(ARGV0 STREQUAL "NAME")
      set(TEST_NAME "${ARGV1}")
    else()
      set(TEST_NAME "${ARGV0}")
    endif()

    list(APPEND ALL_TESTS "${TEST_NAME}")
  endfunction()
endif()
```

However, it does not appear you can set properties on a test defined in another directory.